# Coloring the vertices in my graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles

I am stuck on the following:

> How to color the nodes of a graph in tikz with various colors?

I have written the following code:

```
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (0) at (0,0) {$0$};  
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (4) at (6,0)  {$4$};   
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) at  (3,-1) {$1$};  
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) at  (3,-2) {$2$};  
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (3) at (3,-3) {$3$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (5) at (3,1) {$5$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (6) at (3,2) {$6$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (7) at (3,3) {$7$};  
    \draw (0) -- (1);  
    \draw (0) -- (2);  
    \draw (0) -- (3);  
    \draw (0) -- (4); 
    \draw (0) -- (5);  
    \draw (0) -- (6);  
    \draw (0) -- (7);  
    \draw (4) -- (1);  
    \draw (4) -- (2);  
    \draw (4) -- (3);  
    \draw (4) -- (5);  
    \draw (4) -- (6);  
    \draw (4) -- (7);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I want to color the nodes as red, yellow, etc.
Also I want to color the edges as red, yellow etc.
But I am stuck on how to color the vertices in one figure and the edges in the other figure with different colors.

**Note:** Please let me know how I can modify the existing code to add the colors to the vertices. Please dont suggest a different code altogether.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Do you mean like this: `\node[shape=circle,draw=black, fill=red]`?

Comment: Does that color nodes? I also want to know how to color edges

Comment: To change the color of a draw line use `\draw[red] (4) -- (5);` for example.

Comment: @Sigur; thanks a lot bro

Comment: Hm, did you read the tutorials in part I of the pgfmanual?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=red] (0) at (0,0) {$0$};  
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=yellow] (4) at (6,0)  {$4$};   
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) at  (3,-1) {$1$};  
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) at  (3,-2) {$2$};  
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (3) at (3,-3) {$3$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (5) at (3,1) {$5$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (6) at (3,2) {$6$}; 
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (7) at (3,3) {$7$};  
    \draw[color=red] (0) -- (1);  
    \draw[color=yellow] (0) -- (2);  
    \draw[color=blue] (0) -- (3);  
    \draw[color=purple] (0) -- (4); 
    \draw[color=brown] (0) -- (5);  
    \draw[color=pink] (0) -- (6);  
    \draw[color=green] (0) -- (7);  
    \draw[color=purple] (4) -- (1);  
    \draw[color=brown] (4) -- (2);  
    \draw[color=pink] (4) -- (3);  
    \draw[color=green] (4) -- (5);  
    \draw[color=red]   (4) -- (6);  
    \draw[color=yellow](4) -- (7);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produce the following master peace:

[image]